# How to stop the Post request, if there is already the same data is in the Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to stop the instance if the data matches in the DB. But i tried and failed again and again.

My Code:

models.py

```py
class Doctor(models.Model):
    """
    Manages data of consulting doctors working in the Hospital
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} ({self.department})"


class Patient(models.Model):
    """
    Manages data of patient
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    symptoms = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} ({self.symptoms})"


    class Appointment(models.Model):
        """
        Manages the appointment details
        """
    
        patient_name = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doctor')
        doctor_name = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patient')
        appointment_date = models.DateTimeField()
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.patient_name) + " has appointment with " + str(self.doctor_name)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Patient, Doctor, Appointment


class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Appointment serializer class
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = "__all__"


class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Doctor serializer class
    """
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    patient = AppointmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = "__all__"


class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Patient serializer class
    """

    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    doctor = AppointmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from api.models import Doctor, Patient, Appointment
from api.serializers import DoctorSerializer, PatientSerializer, AppointmentSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.decorators import action

# Create your views here.


class DoctorAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Doctor working in hospitals list
    """

    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer


class PatientAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Patient visiting in hospital list
    """

    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer

class DoctorDetailAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Doctor.objects.filter(patient=pk)


class PatientDetailAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Patient.objects.filter(doctor=pk)


class AppointmentDetailAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        appointment = Appointment.objects.all()
        serializer = AppointmentSerializer(appointment, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = AppointmentSerializer(data=request.data)
        patient_name = Patient.objects.all()
        doctor_name = Doctor.objects.all()
        # print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            appoint_data = Appointment.objects.filter(patient_name=patient_name)
            print(appoint_data)


class AppointmentCreateAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
```

My task:

1. --> TO Resitrict the user to make appointment if there is already an appoinment is schedule to the Doctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add a validation in the serializer to check if an existing appointment already exists like this:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if not self.instance: # I'm creating an appointment
            if Appointment.objects.filter(
                doctor_name=attrs['doctor_name'], 
                appointment_date=attrs['appointment_date'], 
                active=True, 
            ).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    f'Appointment already exists for {attrs['doctor_name']}'
                )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to Django stuck at this point and the project was pending. But now everything is fine and going well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override post method in LISTAPIVIEW and get data which you are going to filter before saving. For example;

```
class DoctorAPI(generics.ListAPIView):

queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
serializer_class = DoctorSerializer

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
     data=request.data.get("the name of input")
     instance = Doctor.objects.filter(the field name which you are going 
     to compare).exist()
     if instance:
     return Response({"error":"This data is in database"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too.